# Why can't OrderedDict be shuffled?

Tags: python-3.x, shuffle, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDict that would like to shuffle like so:

```
od = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
random.shuffle(od)
```

Unfortunately this does not work (python3), and a `KeyError: 0` exception is raised.
The alternative that I have working is to convert to a list, shuffle, and rebuild an OrderedDict:

```
od_tmp = list(od.items())
random.shuffle(od_temp)
od = OrderedDict(od_tmp)
```

Since OrderedDict has an order, it seems reasonable to be able to sort it directly. Converting to a list is inefficient.

The questions are:

- Is there a better way than the solution above? (without resorting to use lists only)
- Why can't I shuffle an OrderedDict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `random.shuffle` an OrderedDict because `random.shuffle` is written with [sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) in mind. The best shuffle algorithm (Fisher-Yates shuffle) unfortunately requires random access to be efficient, but an OrderedDict doesn't offer random access based on the order (only based on the key). There *might* be a clever and fast way to shuffle the underlying linked list, but I'm not aware of any.

You could implement a Fisher-Yates shuffle that iterates in order instead of doing random access, but this would be even slower (quadratic complexity and quite high constants). An option that copies less and constructs no pointless tuples is to shuffle only the keys and then reorders the original OrderedDict:

```
keys = list(od)
random.shuffle(keys)
for key in keys:
    od.move_to_end(key)
```

But I'm not sure whether this is more readable and aesthetic.